# Есть ли команда для создания проекта с webpack?

Tags: html, css, webpack, frontend

Вопрос в заголовке. Поясню, что я имею в виду. Есть ли такая команда, с помощью которой получаем проект для верстки, в котором уже будет настроена структура проекта, webpack, liveserver и фичи для разбиения по компонентам.
Команды типо `npx create-new-app` как в React?
Или всё-таки нужно для каждого нового проекта повторять снова и снова?

Comment: `create-new-app` это бойлерплейт для создания проектов. Можно поискать и другие

Comment: из коробки у вебпака такой команды нет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что не знал как это правильно загуглить. Запрос `webpack scss bem` решил проблему и я нашел очень похожее решение. Вдруг кому-то понадобится. [Держите](https://nicothin.pro/page/my-start-kit). [И еще](https://github.com/andreyalexeich/gulp-scss-starter) Здесь подробно всё описано. Конфигурация следующая:

- Webpack & Gulp
- BEM
- Sass (Scss)

Также существует простое создание блоков следующим образом:

```
node createBlock.js new-block pug js
```

Созданный блок окажется в `src/blocks/new-block` с двумя пустыми подпапками для изображений, scss-, pug- и js-файлов.